# Memory Network overfits

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, natural-language, recurrent-neural-network

I'm playing with a [MemN2N](https://github.com/ishalyminov/memn2n) on the babi-dialog-task 1 (API calls). And a very surprising thing I see is that it learns dialogues pretty well, but on the most interesting part, actual API calls, it's pretty terrible (0.7%). And I think it makes sense because there are only 7 distinct interlocutory responses but 159 distinct api_calls in the trainset.

**UPD**: if trained exclusively on API calls, its per-utterance accuracy is at 96% training and 0% which makes me think it does nothing but memorize its training data.

My MemN2N hyperparameters are as follows:

- 20 embedding size
- 3 hops
- 12 memory size
- 100 training epochs

My MemN2N input is `<story, question, answer>` triplets where story is all turns prior to the current question. I don't use any indices of supporting facts.
If you worked with a MemN2N for dialogue tasks, did you notice a similar behavior? And maybe have an idea of how to fix it?

**UPD**: tried an LSTM solution for that (encoded dialogue context --> answer label) - results are the same :(

**UPD2**: seems like I've found a way around imbalanced class label set - incorporating class weights into the loss function. But what still keeps me surprised is, both MemN2N and LSTM trained to predict exclusively API calls perform particularly bad (2-3% accuracy in general).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem was quite conceptual: the way answers are represented differs significantly in bAbI QA and bAbI Dialog setups (while the way they're predicted is the same - it's just class labels).

So if you notice some similar behavior, please check that answer prediction step in your model corresponds to "Choosing the response" formula in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.07683.pdf) (page 11).

Or you could just use [my implementation](https://github.com/ishalyminov/memn2n):)